# Deleting artifacts in artifactory

Tags: artifactory, artifacts

I want to delete artifacts in artifactory.I googled and found this link 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Here the Delete build,using REST API,is what we are going for at the moment.Can any one give me a general idea how the command should look using curl command.Also in buildname what do i need to specify?

Answer (score 27):

For deleting a single artifact or folder you should use the [Delete Item](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) API, for example

```
curl -uadmin:password -XDELETE http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.9
```

Notice that you will need a user with delete permissions.
If all goes well you should expect a response with a 204 status and no content.

The delete API is intended for deleting build information and is relevant if you are using the Artifactory [build integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration).

Comment: I received `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`.  `Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST`

Comment: Put a space after "-u" and "-X" in order to work, i.e., ```curl -u admin:password -X DELETE ```.

Comment: I use this command but i got not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there's a tool that can be used for it (note that I am a contributor to that tool):

https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory-cleanup

> Assume i have 10 repositories and i want to keep only last 20 artifacts in 5 repositories and unlimited in other 5 repositories

The rule for 10 repositories would look like:

```yaml
# artifactory-cleanup.yaml
artifactory-cleanup:
  server: https://repo.example.com/artifactory
  # $VAR is auto populated from environment variables
  user: $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
  password: $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD

  policies:
    - name: reponame
      rules:
        - rule: Repo
          name: "reponame"
        - rule: KeepLatestNFiles
          count: 20
```

Comment: When linking to a website, blog or repo to which you have affiliation, you **must explicitly disclose your involvement**. Otherwise, your post may be flagged as spam.

Comment: @AdrianMole hi, thank you for the note, didn't know that rule! Is there a special flag for it in SO or I just should have mentioned like "I've contributed in the tool"?

Comment: Something like what I have just edited in will normally suffice. I don't actually think you *are* a spammer, but [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) may be of some help.

Comment: @AdrianMole thank you for your work and the advice, appreciate it! 
I'm not a spammer, rather a newbie, but we behave the same sometimes...